# Login screen upside down

Tags: display, laptop

So I've recently bought a new **[HP ProBook 440 G5](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/laptops/product-detail.html?oid=17047134)** and installed elementaryOS (*version missing*). It's a dual-boot alongside with Windows 10 (that's likely irrelevant but mentioning just in case).

Anyway, when my laptop is connected to a monitor (via HDMI/VGA) everything is fine. Both screens display everything well. Then I've noticed that when I disconnect the laptop from the monitor, the screen content flips around (upside down, sideways) when I move the lid around. I've googled this problem and found that there is a command

```
xrandr -o normal
```

which I'm supposed to add as a startup task. And this works, kinda. The screen doesn't flip anymore while I'm logged in. But as soon as I log out, the login screen goes haywire again.

It's not really that bad, the only problem is when the password field is not in focus so I have to use my touchpad to click it, while my screen is flipped.

Any way to solve this permanently?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you added that command?
(_`xrandr -o normal`_)

Comment: Settings > Applications > Startup

Answer (score 2):

### FIRST METHOD

**Create** a file, I'll name it `no-flip.sh`, in `/opt`

`sudo nano /opt/no-flip.sh`

**Copy** this text and **paste** it into the file and **save** it

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
xrandr -o normal
```

---

**Execute**

`sudo chmod a+rx /opt/no-flip.sh`

**Edit**

`sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

**Add the lines**

```
[SeatDefaults]
display-setup-script=/opt/no-flip.sh
```

**Reboot**

---

I used `nano` as my text editor, you can use anyone you like

---

### SECOND METHOD

Create the file `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/45custom_xrandr-settings` write in it:

```
# To configure xrandr automatically during the first login,
# save this script to your computer as /etc/X11/Xsession.d/45custom_xrandr-settings:

# Based on https://askubuntu.com/a/678301/890782

# No Flip
xrandr -o normal
```

---

### NOTE

This should work, at least in theory. Right now doesn't work because you ran the command in the user environment hence when you log out from that user that process is terminated. The theory is that you need to run the command system-wide, and this is one possible method.

Comment: I don't have that .conf file that you mentioned. There is a filed named lightdm.conf.d , but it's empty

Comment: create it, with the same commands with `nano` will work... you have to know how to save with `nano`. if you don't use the text editor you like, it doesn't matter

Comment: Well I've done this, but now I can't boot into elementary? Just stuck at the logo. Could this be connected or just a coincidence?

Comment: Which logo? Because you just changed a config in the greeter (graphical part) but the system loads before that. If it's the system's logo then this config isn't load at all yet or is loaded but below you have the system running without problems only the X has problems that can be solved. If you mean at the greeter (where you choose the account and type the password) then we just have to rollback the config and try another way. Again.. which logo

Comment: The elementaryOS logo (the circled letter 'e'). It just stands there glowing forever.

Comment: weird... then just press CTRL+ALT+F2... login into that "terminal" and remove the line you added to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` or the file completely if you only have that line in it. If you are unable to change to the terminal with the shortcuts, don't know what could be the cause of this becasue is like having a flat tyre and then i tell you to change the tyre ..you do it ...but you then tell me that the car doesn't start... anyway there is another way to remove the conf i made you write but try this first then i'll tell you another

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86999/discussion-between-sebastian-and-koy).